# Assistance with MySQL Advanced SUM and GroupBy Month Case

Tags: mysql

I have the following query, but I am stuck and am unsure where to go next with our museum's management application.

```
SELECT name,
       account_number,
       CASE
           WHEN p.method = 'cash'
                OR p.method = 'mo'
                OR p.method = 'check'
                THEN
                    MONTH(p.created_at)
                    ELSE
                        MONTH(p2.created_at)
                        END

FROM cemetery_charge_types
LEFT JOIN invoices i on cemetery_charge_types.id = i.charge_type_id
LEFT JOIN payment_details pd on i.id = pd.payable_id
LEFT JOIN payments p on pd.payment_id = p.id
LEFT JOIN payouts p2 on p.payout_id = p2.id
BETWEEN '2022-06-01 00:00:00' AND '2022-06-30 00:00:00'
WHERE cemetery_charge_types.category = 'Court'
GROUP BY account_number
ORDER BY account_number
```

If the `p` (payments) `method` is "cash, mo, or check" I want to group by month of `p.created_at` and SUM by `pd.amount`.

But if the `p` (payments) `method` is "card or terminal", I want to group by month of `p2.created_at`.

I still want it grouped by the `account_number` and to add the sums of both groups together.

So if cash, check or mo methods had a total of $100 for month 6 and a total of $0 for month 7.
And if card and terminal methods had a total of $50 for month 6 and a total of $75 for month 7,
I would want it to look like:

`ACCT #      MONTH 6   MONTH 7`

`Account 1   $150      $75`

Is this at all possible, or does anyone have any suggestions of where I could look?

Comment: Adding sample data would help your question.

Comment: This question needs a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Pattern:

```sql
SELECT {common columns},
       CASE WHEN {condition 1} THEN {expression 1}
            WHEN {condition 2} THEN {expression 2}
            END AS grouping_expression,
       SUM( CASE WHEN {condition 1} THEN {value 1}
                 WHEN {condition 2} THEN {value 2}
                 END ) AS result_expression
FROM {tableset}
GROUP BY {common columns}, 
         grouping_expression
```

Answer (score 0):

Table structure with sample data will help to understand question.
That CASE statement must go as part of Group clause.